# jquery ajax post string when a user clicks on a check box?

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

I am using jquery and ajax to update a record in my database once a user clicks a checkbox.

I am trying to post a string value so that my query can insert this string value into the database.

like so:

page 1.php

```
$date_check = 'a very special date';

Click here to agree to our terms <checkbox id="terms_check">

    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
    //alert('Document is ready');

                    $('#terms_check').change(function() {
                        var sel_stud = $(this).val();
                        var sel_stud2 = $date_check;
    //alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "include/process_terms.php",

                            data: {theOption: sel_stud, theOption2: sel_stud2}, 
                            success: function(whatigot) {
    //alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            window.location = 'dashboard.php';     
                            } //END success fn
                        }); //END $.ajax
                    }); //END dropdown change event
                }); //END document.ready
            </script>
```

page 2.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'config.php';

//Get value posted in by ajax
    $date_check = $_POST['theOption2'];

$query = sprintf("UPDATE supplier_users, supplier_stats SET supplier_users.terms_agreed = '1', supplier_users.terms_agreed_date = $date_check, supplier_stats.complete_count = supplier_stats.complete_count+ 1 WHERE supplier_users.user_id='{$_SESSION['id']}' AND supplier_users.terms_agreed = '0'");
$result = mysql_query($query);


$_SESSION['message2'] = '<div id="message_box2"><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div><h23>Thank You!</h23><p>You have successfully accept the Supply & General Purchasing Term&#39;s and Condition&#39;s.</p> </div>';
?>
```

The problem is that my jquery isn't executing my ajax and nothing is happening.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error message or the problem ?

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi have updated my question at the bottom thanks

Comment: only one data: is enough in ajax request

Comment: You're overriding the first data: with the second one. Also, check the network tab in your browser to see if the ajax request is firing. Check the console for errors.

Comment: the ajax works on my other scripts. how can I see whats preventing this particular script from firing?

Comment: insert the debugger , check if it is firing ?Check the console for error .

Answer (score 0):

First line `$date_check = 'a very special date'`
should have semi colon at last ";"..it may shows unexpected error.

This cause unknown error in php..Please have a look.

Add below code to debug code.

```
error: 
    function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
}
```

Check with errorThrown received and post it so that will get idea of error.

Comment: no sorry that's just my typing mistake on here, it actually does have a semi colon after it so that can't be the cause